# How to access viewmodel's property value in custom validation attribute to alter messages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

The viewmodel has many string properties like `Sample` as below. My requirement is to show different validation messages depending on a bool flag in my viewmodel. That flag is  `IsProposer` property as mentioned below:

```
[SampleAttribute(true, "bla prop", "foo add driver")]       
public string Sample { get; set; }

public bool IsProposer { get; set; }
```

I thought to create a validation attribute so that I can just place it on all my string properties (required validation). And then depending on the value of that boolean flag, I will pass the msg accordingly. My custom validation attribute is as follows:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
    public class SampleAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {
        protected string ProposerErrorMessage { get; set; }
        protected string AdditionalDriverErrorMessage { get; set; }
        protected bool IsProposer { get; set; }
        public SampleAttribute(bool isProposer, string propmsg, string adddrivermsg)
        {
            ProposerErrorMessage = propmsg;
            IsProposer = isProposer;
            AdditionalDriverErrorMessage = adddrivermsg;

        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (IsValid(value))
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult(IsProposer ? ProposerErrorMessage : AdditionalDriverErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the issue is, as you can see I am just passing true as first parameter for the attribute. Here, I need to pass the `Isproposer` property's value from the viewmodel instance so that I can then act accordingly. How can I access it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a attribute like this:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// This validation attribute is an extension to RequiredAttribute that can be used to choose either of the two 
    /// validation messages depending on a property in the context of same model.
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
    public class RequiredExtensionAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {
        private string _errorMessageIfTruthy;
        private string _errorMessageIfFalsy; 
        private string _dependentProperty;

        public RequiredExtensionAttribute(string dependentproperty, string errorMessageIfTruthy, string errorMessageIfFalsy)
        {
            _errorMessageIfTruthy = errorMessageIfTruthy;
            _dependentProperty = dependentproperty;
            _errorMessageIfFalsy = errorMessageIfFalsy;

        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var propertyTestedInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this._dependentProperty);
            if (propertyTestedInfo == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("unknown property {0}", this._dependentProperty));
            }

            var propertyTestedValue = propertyTestedInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (IsValid(value))
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult((bool)propertyTestedValue ? _errorMessageIfTruthy : _errorMessageIfFalsy);
            }
        }
    }
```

This can now be used in models like:

```
[RequiredExtensionAttribute("IsProposerViewModel", "Please select your employment status.", "Please select this driver's employment status")]       
public string EmploymentStatus { get; set; }
public bool IsProposerViewModel { get; set; }
```

-where the first parameter for attribute is the `IsProposerViewModel`, the dependent value.

Comment: Fixed my problem this did.  Happy I am.

Comment: what about when the `IsProposerViewModel` property comes before the `EmploymentStatus`? what about when theyre circular properties?