# ASP.net Web API 2 ModelState always valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-web-api2

After reviewing several articles and SO questions, I still cannot understand why my validation attributes are not triggering.

For simplicity, I have reduced my model and added the string `testing` to debug.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PublicApi
{
  public class CostStandardRequest
  {
    [DateLessThan("EndDate", ErrorMessage = "StartDate must be less than EndDate")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string testing { get; set; }
  }
}
```

In my controller, I test my method by passing a `null` value to the testing attribute in my `CostStandardRequest` class. However, `ModelState.IsValid` returns true despite null values.:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> PostCostingStandard(CostStandardRequest request)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // always valid
  }
  else
  {
    // never runs
  }
}
```

I've reached this point by following the guide [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)

Note: ModelState.IsValid is true even when my custom validation attribute [DateLessThan] should be returning a `ValidationResult(ErrorMessage)`. I have not included this code, but I can if it's deemed relevant.

Comment: It's unclear to me. Are you testing the running code (ie. running it but with a test value you expect to fail)? **Or** are you executing a Unit Test and have created an instance of this controller and passed in a null value to the method?

Comment: How did you implemented **DateLessThan**? That is a custom attribute. Can you post the code for that class? Did read this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx?

Comment: This seems like a very similiar approach to your custom **DateLessThan** custom attribute. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18912068/3973463
Verify your implementation is similar to that one.

Comment: @AlfredoA. I am using the definition laid out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41901736/4249881)

Comment: @Igor that right! I'm using a unit test and creating a new instance of my controller, then passing in a request object where `string testing = null`

Comment: @BenGraham - Then this is expected because the model validates as a part of the pipeline which you are bypassing in the unit test. This is a good thing because of SoC (separation of concerns) so you are not required to test your model inside the controller (the 2 can be isolated).

Comment: @Igor ahh that makes sense. I just tested this with the running instance and it works as expected. If you respond with a writeup, I'll accept your answer for other users to find.

Comment: You are mixing two concepts here. The controller is not responsible for the validation. The pipeline is, this answer will explain it in much more detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/22563585/3973463

Comment: @BenGraham - Good deal. I found some existing questions (you are/were not the only one with this question) and marked yours as a duplicate of those. They have much better write ups than I could think of at the moment so it is more helpful that way (IMO).